# PHP gethostbyname() returning Name instead of IP when the name is passed in as a variable rather than a string literal

Tags: php, gethostbyname

PHP gethostbyname() returning Name instead of IP when the name is passed in as a variable rather than a string literal

I have seen similar problems with some valuable discussion but nothing that this this head on.

If I pass a varible say $domain to gethostbyname() where $domain is the string value created by a foreach loop, the return value is always exactly what I put into to it -- for example if $domain =="google.com" the return value is google.com. Calling the same function gethostbyname() with a string literal I get the IP address. gethostbyname('google.com')

Is this a known bug? Is there a workaround? I'll be grateful for any help.

Thank you

This code fails -- producing the value of $url for a result:

```
foreach ($this->domainNames as $url){

            $ips[]=gethostbyname($url); 

    }
```

The second set of code gives the correct ip address twice (once for each value in $this->domainNames:

```
foreach ($this->domainNames as $url){

            $ips[]=gethostbyname('google.com'); 

    }
```

SOLUTION: 
This turned out to be caused some some sloppy spaces in my varible which were fixed using trim when creating my $this->domainNames array values.

Comment: Please post specific code where this problem occurs. I tried it and it gives me back the IP address, not the name..

Comment: As we don't know what is inside $this->domainNames we still can't help you. Please also provide a dump of $this->domainNames by doing a `var_dump($this->domainNames);`

Comment: Laurens $this-domainName at the moment has been stripped to an array that contains two strings both 'google.com' -- when I enter the exact values (cut and paste) into the function I get IP addresses, when I enter the vars from the foreachloop I get the data I put in (unless I put in an invalid domain name then I get an error)

Comment: Then show me a var_dump, because if what you say is true, then it should work (see my updated answer)

Comment: Impossible to debug without the values of domain names.

Comment: The image I just added shows the values I am sending and getting in return

Comment: Show is the whole code! From storing it in the `domain_server` array to storing it in the `dnsIP` array. The mistake is not a bug in `gethostbyname()` as I showed in my answer. It has to be something else. Show us everything!

Comment: Thank you for your help, I was able to fix the code by adding trim() to my vars gethostbyname(trim($name:);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will do this when `gethostbyname()` fails. From the PHP manual:

> Returns the IPv4 address or a string containing the unmodified hostname on failure.

What you are claiming is not true. This:

```
<?php
$domainNames = array("google.com", "google.com");

foreach ($domainNames as $url){
    echo gethostbyname($url); 
}
```

Outputs: `74.125.136.139` twice

Please provide a dump of $domainNames, so we can see what is really happening.